# How to get an object with it's parent from firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get from firebese an object that have a specific value and this object parent's name. But in some reasons I cant do it.

So first of all I will describe what I have:
Db with the next structure:

```
db
|
+--clients
       |
       +--kua
       |   |
       |   +--kuaName1
       |   |
       |   +--kuaName2
       |   |
       |   +--kuaName3
       |
       +--uo
```

In every kuaName I have an object with some info, one of the keys is "kuaEdrpou", the value of this key is unique for every kuaName. So I have next logic:

1. Find an object by kuaEdrpou.
2. Take this object name (kuaName1, kuaName2, kuaName3) and data to use them in my app.

Also I have function to get data from firebase db:

```
const stocksRef = firebase.database().ref().child('clients/kua');
stocksRef.orderByChild('kuaEdrpou').equalTo(this.state.kuaEdrpou).once("value",snapshot => {
    let snap = snapshot.exportVal();
    console.log("snapshot", snap);
}
```

Console.log shows me an object with three keys
[image]

So my questions are how to get from firebase
{kuaName1:{kuaEdrpou: some id}} object and why snapshot.exportVal() returns an object with three nested objects inside?

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the snapshot on ref

```
firebase.database().ref().child('clients/kua');
```

so whenever something change/updates you get the whole kua with all of its child.

if you need any specific child under kua add the reference of that children like

```
firebase.database().ref().child(`clients/kua/${this.state.kuaEdrpou}`);
```

maybe this way you can get your desired object

Comment: Got snapshot null